# How can i listen to Dockerized .NET web application

Tags: asp.net, .net, docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile

I am unable to listen to the containarizred Docker .NET application. However it is working fine outside of the container and i am able to see the webpage over the localhost:

**Here is my Docker File** : ( This is just use case which i am trying to run )

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:2.2
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./publish .

ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT hero
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:5000
EXPOSE 5000

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Reporting.Service.dll"]
```

and i am running the container after successfuly creating the image like this

```
docker run -it --name mycontainer myimage
```

Resultant is the following

```
Hosting environment: hero
Content root path: /app
Now listening on: http://[::]:5000
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

I am trying to get it on http://localhost:5000 or trying to use the containers IP but couldn't succeed as well with the port mapping, can some point what's more needed in it?

Comment: You need to specify the `-p` like `docker run -it --name mycontainer -p 5000:5000 myimage`